# Using a package from another distribution

Tags: 12.04

I installed Desmume on Ubuntu 12.04, but the latest version is only 0.9.7 and I want the speed boost from 0.9.9. The only way I see is to compile the source code myself, which I try not to do as much as possible. Now I noticed this a few times, that higher number of distributions have higher number of releases for lots of packages. Is there no ppa that lets you use these packages anyway instead of having to find a workaround around this all the time. So I was wondering did I make a mistake installing 12.04? I don't feel like I did, but if so many packages are outdated, should I upgrade?

Anyway the original question was if there was a way to use the package from lets Saucy or Trusty in Precise?

Comment: You can try it, but I wouldn't expect that to work (libraries tend to change over time). [Here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/getdeb_games/precise/games/getdeb/desmume) is a site with 0.9.8-1 for precise and it links to [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/getdeb_games?dist=precise) for a PPA.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch After trying to get this to work for some time, I just downloaded the latest exe file, opened it with PlayOnLinux and it worked out of the box.

Comment: usually, running in an emulator is slower then running the native version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you want more up to date software, of course you should upgrade.  You might try downloading the package from a newer release from packages.launchpad.net and installing it with `sudo dpkg -i whatever.deb`.  It sometimes works, but is not supported, and you probably will run into dependency issues.